# Access classes property of Class property

Tags: c#, if-statement, properties, foreach

Code:

```
 public class ClassA
 {
      public decimal foo
 }

 public class ClassB
 {
   public List<ClassA> Alist 
 }
```

inside ClassB I am populating values to Alist like so.

```
      foreach (junk in trash)
        {              
            Alist.add(new ClassA()
            {                   
                foo = junk.Bar
            });     
          // if (Alist.foo == whatever)
          // but  no access to Alist.foo here 
        }
```

Inside the for each loop I'm trying to run an if statement against foo. 
So something like  `if (Alist.foo == whatever)`
I can't do this, it doesn't give me access to `Alist.foo`. Any idea how this would be done.

Comment: Your syntax, as displayed, is not able to compile.  Try to post real code, or at least code that would work...

Comment: Yes, I left some things out, but this is the general idea of my question. Do I have to use a for loop instead? If that's the case I should be able to do what I want

Comment: Hard to tell, but you may be looking for the indexer, as in `Alist[0].foo`, but since the code is incomplete, I'm not sure.

Comment: `Alist.add(new Alist()`....do you mean `new ClassA`?

Comment: yes, it seems I can do what I want  using `junk.foo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you don't have a reference to the object you just added. There are a lot of ways to get this. I'm going to recommend you simply build the object outside the `Add`.

```
var newA = new ClassA()
{                   
    foo = junk.Bar
};

// now you can perform the if statement
if (newA.foo == someValue)
{
    // do something
}

Alist.add(newA);
```

Comment: I can get access using `junk.foo` inside my foreach what do you think about that?

Comment: @CSharper, are you saying just access the `decimal` value on `junk` instead for the `if` statement? Yes, that's another possible approach.

Comment: yea that's what I need, I guess I'll just access it has a described, shouldn't be an issue

Comment: @CSharper, I'm glad I could be of assistance.